# How do I refresh/extend the remember_me cookie (expiry) after logging in using the remember_me feature?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.3 LTS.

I can fully use the `remember_me` feature in Symfony, including setting it and logging back in after session expiry. However my issue is that once the user is logged back in with the `remember_me` feature then the expiry isn't refreshed.

In other words, if you set the "lifetime" of the `remember_me` cookie to 14 days then regardless of how many time the user visits the site they will always need to re-authenticate with a full username/password (after 14 days.) I don't want to set a longer cookie as 14 days without visiting seems right.

I know how to manually set the `remember_me` cookie. I just need to know where to put that code.

I've tried these:

1. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605681/how-to-prolong-the-remember-me-cookie-on-each-request-in-symfony2) doesn't do what I want and is very different.
2. There doesn't appear to be any settings in the `security.yml` configuration (to refresh expiry.)
3. Hooking in on the `processAutoLoginCookie` method in `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices`, but that can't work as there's no access to a Response (to set the cookie manually.)
4. Listening on the `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event looks a good idea, but [`InteractiveLoginEvent`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Event/InteractiveLoginEvent.html) doesn't have access to the Response either. [Here's an example.](https://gist.github.com/snc/1312769)
5. I could get messy by setting a request attribute using one of the above and then setting a response listener to detect for that, but I think that's too messy. There must be a better way to do it.
6. I could use one of the above to listen on the request, generate a response (e.g. redirect), set the cookie, perform the redirect, but again that's not good enough.

Comment: Have you tried to create an event listener using onKernelRequest event and to insert your code in this function ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. A cookie can only be set in the Response. A lot of this is mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proposed approach:

1. Set up a `kernel.response` listener
2. Pass the `SecurityContext` to the listener constructor
3. Detect a logged in user
4. Manually set your `remember_me` cookie
5. Set a session var to prevent future cookie sets
6. Your new cookie will piggyback on the next page a user loads when logged in using the `remember_me` cookie.

### services.yml

```
services:
    acme.response_listener:
        class: AcmeBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener
        arguments: ['@security.context']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

### ResponseListener

```
namespace AcmeBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

class ResponseListener
{
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    private $securityContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
        if (
            $this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') // remember_me cookie used
            && !$session->get('cookie_extended') // cookie hasn't been extended
        ) {
            $response = $event->getResponse(); // get the Response object
            $cookie = new Cookie(...); // your cookie
            $response->headers->setCookie($cookie); // set that cookie!
            $session->set('cookie_extended', true); // prevent future cookie sets for the current session
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but it should be enough theory to get you started in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

The expiry timestamp and the password are both part of the hash of the cookie value, so it seems that the rememberme cookie can only be set at login since the password must be available to extend the timestamp.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069098:

> If you are setting the rememberme cookie directly, you have to use the following format:
>
> ```
> base64_encode(<classname>:base64_encode(<username>):<expiry-timestamp>:<hash>)
> ```
>
> where the hash will be:
>
> ```
> sha256(<classname> . <username> . <expiry-timestamp> . <password> . <key>)
> ```